# Programming the NEM blockchain & storing ipfs hash

Tags: blockchain, ipfs, nem

I am looking at integrating an IPFS content hash into the NEM/Mijin blockchain. If I attach the ipfs Hash in the message section of a mosaic, will this be actually added to the blockchain, or do I need to add the hash as part of the mosaic name, but how do suggest doing this as the mosaic name doesn't accept capital letters?

When I view my profiles account transactions, the mosaic is shown but not the message. Is there away of recovering the message included with the transaction?

ie is there a command to recover the block transaction inc the message?
S nem2-cli account tranasactions --profile   doesn't recover the message details?

just:
Recipient, Mosaics, Signer, Deadline and Hash

I’m using nem2-cli and the MIJIN_TEST network

If you can give me some suggestions., or pass on the message who can. I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the hash of the ipfs to the message of a mosaic, it will be stored in the blockchain.

If you use:

```
nem2-cli transaction info -- profile your-profile --hash the-hash-of-transaction
```

you should be able to see the message in the transaction.

If you do not have the transaction hash you can find it with the use of this command:

```
nem2-cli account transactions --profile your-profile  --publickey the-publicAccount-were-you-send-the-transation-to
```